# Dplyr: Rename Tibble Output Columns With Factor Levels

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a way to rename my factor levels (1, 2, 3) with girl, boy, other in the dplyr tibble output.

This is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
dplyr::group_by(sex)%>%
dplyr::summarise(percent=100*n()/nrow(df1), n=n())
```

And my result is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  sexs    percent    n
   <int>   <dbl> <int>
1      1  52.1     731
2      2  47.1     661
3     NA   0.855    12
```

The desired result would be:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      sexs    percent    n
       <int>   <dbl> <int>
Girl     1  52.1     731
Boy      2  47.1     661
Other   NA   0.855    12
```

Comment: These are `row_names/row.names` not levels. Could you add your data with `dput(head(df,n))`?

Answer (score 1):

I happen to love the `forcats` package because when I get done I can actually see what I did.  Another solution by simply adding to the pipe before your existiung code.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

sex <- sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE)
sex[[88]] <- NA
df1 <- data.frame(sex)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(newsex = fct_explicit_na(fct_recode(as_factor(sex), 
                                             Girl = "1", 
                                             Boy = "2" ), 
                                  na_level = "Other")) %>% 
  group_by(newsex, sex) %>%
  summarise(percent = 100 * n() / nrow(df1), n=n())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   newsex [3]
#>   newsex   sex percent     n
#>   <fct>  <int>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1 Girl       1      56    56
#> 2 Boy        2      43    43
#> 3 Other     NA       1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When posting please provide some sample data to work with, it will help others test and make sure everything is working properly. This problem is relatively simple so it shouldn't be a problem.

If you want to replace the NA with literally any other number you can do this

```
df1 %>%
    dplyr::mutate(sex = ifelse(is.na(sex), 0, sex),
                  sex = factor(sex, 
                               levels = c(1,2,0), 
                               labels = c("Girl", "Boy", "Other"))) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(sex)%>%
    dplyr::summarise(percent=100*n()/nrow(df1), n=n())
```

Otherwise you can use case_when to assign the factors and then convert the column to a factor

```
 df1 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sex = case_when(
                                sex == 1 ~ "Girl",
                                sex == 2 ~ "Boy",
                                is.na(sex) ~ "Other") %>% 
  as_factor(.)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(sex)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(percent=100*n()/nrow(df1), n=n())
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data I am working with is classified. Can you tell me where I can find free sample datasets that include a gender variable that I can share?

Comment: I don't know where there is one, but there might be nuance to your dataset that isn't present in the test set. Any way you could share a deidentified subset or even a subset with the numbers made up? Did you try running these snippets? They should work

Comment: Both options work like a charm and are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to keep the original ranking and prevent the tibble from being in alphabetical order?

Comment: you mean in order of girl, boy, other? in the first example if you code other to a 3, and then `arrange(sex)` after summarize it should maintain the order.